# Tri-linear interpolation in compute shader

Tags: opengl, interpolation, raycasting, compute-shader

I want to ray cast a line through an `image3D` grid. Now, if I hit a voxel I would like to have the tri-linear interpolated value of the neighbouring 8 voxels.

Is that even possible with the compute shader? I know with `sampler2D` the bi-linear interpolation is intrinsically hardware supported.

Of course, I can write the code manually myself. However, that would literally kill the nice performance.

Comment: Why not use a `texture3D` instead of an `image3D`?

Comment: You answered your own question, you just somehow didn't connect the dots ;) Sampling is supported in compute, and it extends to 1D and 3D. Incidentally, do you really mean tri-linear filtering here? That involves the min/mag and mip filter being set to linear. Mipmaps in 3D textures are a little convoluted to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to ray cast a line through an image3D grid. Now, if I hit a voxel I would like to have the tri-linear interpolated value of the neighbouring 8 voxels.

Then cast it through a `sampler3D` instead of an `image3D` grid.